# Функция, которая плавно увеличит размер div и покажет все данные в нем

Tags: jquery, функции

Здравствуйте! Столкнулся с одним вопросом: подскажите, пожалуйста, есть `div`, в нем тег, при нажатии на тег должна выполняться `jquery` функция `fade` или `slide` (слабо разбираюсь в `jquery`), которая плавно увеличит размер дива и покажет все данные в нем. Подскажите, как это можно сделать на `jquery`. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('link').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
  $('div').animate({
     width : 400,
     height : 400
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы имеете в виду что-то типа [этого](http://jsfiddle.net/oneboy/zGYvd/) ? Или я неправильно понял.

Comment: Что бы увеличить див, нужно использовать функцию animate, которая анимирует ксс свойства елементов.

Comment: согласен... но и помимо animate еще есть несколко вариантов решения данной задачи

Comment: @oneboy, @markuper,  Так и до холивара не далеко )) В вопросе есть упоминание и про изменение размера, и о том, что в этом элементе должны появляться данные. Поэтому вы оба в своем роде правы. А от автора хотелось бы уточнений. Забудьте про jQuery и опишите сам процесс и желаемый результат действий.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('link').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('div').slideDown(300)
});
```